# How can i use SQLAlchemy back_populates if one of my tables has 2 foreing keys

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

These are my models:

```
class Inventory(Base):
    __tablename__ = "inventories"
    inventory_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    transfers_origin: Mapped[List["Transfer"]] = relationship(back_populates="inventory_origin")
    transfers_destination: Mapped[List["Transfer"]] = relationship(back_populates="inventory_destination")

class Transfer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "transfers"
    transfer_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    date: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(server_default=func.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    inventory_origin_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("inventories.inventory_id"))
    inventory_origin: Mapped["Inventory"] = relationship(foreign_keys=[inventory_origin_id], back_populates="transfers_origin")
    inventory_destination_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("inventories.inventory_id"))
    inventory_destination: Mapped["Inventory"] = relationship(foreign_keys=[inventory_destination_id], back_populates="transfers_destination")
```

But when i run the application a receive this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Inventory.transfers_origin - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

I am testing AsyncSession, and i am trying to use the Declarative models but i am new and i do not understand how to properly configure the relationship.

I want to be able to join all transfers from an inventory, destination and origin.

Answer (score 0):

I was only missing:

```
relationship(back_populates="inventory_destination",foreign_keys="Transfer.inventory_origin_id")
```